# Программно изменить реестр через WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, реестр

Здравствуйте! Скажу сразу, это проблемная для меня тема. В ветви *`HKEY_CURRENT_USER`* нужно изменить значение `ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity`, находящееся в *`Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM`*. По стандарту оно равно 30, мне нужно выставить 0. Тип REG_DWORD. Как я делаю:

```
HKEY hkey;
RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM\\", 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hkey);

LPTSTR lpName = L"ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity";
LPTSTR lpValueEx = L"0";

RegSetValueEx(hkey,
    lpName,
    0,
    REG_SZ,
    (LPBYTE)lpValueEx,
    (DWORD)(lstrlen(lpValueEx) + 1)*sizeof(TCHAR));
```

Но ничего не происходит. GetLastError возвращает 0. Что я делаю не так?

**Обновлено**

```
HKEY hkey;
RegOpenKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM", &hkey);

LPTSTR lpName = L"ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity";
LPTSTR lpValueEx = L"0";

RegSetValueEx(hkey, L"ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity", 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)lpValueEx, (DWORD)sizeof(lpValueEx));
```

Вот так получается. Вроде меняется **но**, отсчёт значений которые я передаю, как бы идёт от 30. То есть - я передаю `lpValueEx = L"0"`, `ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity` становиться равным 30. Передаю, например 1, параметр соответственно становиться равным 31. Если передать 10 и больше, то параметр принимает какое-то другое значение, а при `lpValueEx = L"А"` - нет, не 40, а 41 почему-то. **Что я опять не так делаю?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала нужно вызвать функцию типа RegOpenKey() и передать в нее subkey (без имени параметра!), а уже потом, используя ее разультат, использовать RegSetValueEx(), передавая в нее имя параметра.

Comment: `RegOpenKey(0,L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\DWM\\",...)`, или я не так понял?

Comment: А зачем ноль первым параметром? Надо корректный HKEY_ указать

Comment: @Владимир_Мартьянов, я не понял, что Вы подразумевали под "*без имени параметра*"

Comment: @АртурКлочко у вас имя параметра - ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity, его в RegOpenKey не надо.

Comment: так я его и не передавал туда. Значение начало меняться, но всё равно проблемы. Я обновил вопрос и добавил это туда, посмотрите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

А проблема "0" -> 30 и "A" -> 41 в том, что там тип данных - REG_DWORD, а не строка. Код символа "0" - как раз 0x30, для "A" - 0x41. Пишите туда dword, а не строку.

Comment: `DWORD lpValueEx = (DWORD)0;

 RegSetValueEx(hkey, L"ColorizationGlassReflectionIntensity", 0, REG_DWORD, (PBYTE)lpValueEx, (DWORD)sizeof(lpValueEx));` ничего не происходит

Comment: Короче, выкрутился как обычно, просто стал передавать "\0". Спасибо за ответы!